# Help:For what $ \alpha $ do the integrals exist?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let 
$ K_R (y) \subset \mathbb{R}^n $
be  an n-dimensional Ball with radius $R>0$ and midpoint $y \in \mathbb{R}^n $

Far what $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ n \in \mathbb{N}\{0\} $ do following integrals exist:

$ \int_{K{_R(y)}} |x-y|^{\alpha}dx $

$ \int_{ \mathbb{R}^n \setminus K{_R(y)}} |x-y|^{\alpha}dx $

$ \int_{ \mathbb{R}^n } |x-y|^{\alpha}dx $

with what criteria can i solve this task?
I don't know how to begin.
Thanks for any help!!

Let's take 
$ \int_{K{_R(y)}} |x-y|^{\alpha}dx $ ,$y=0, n=2 $

If I replace by polarcoordinates $ x= rsin \phi $ :
$ \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^R | r|^{\alpha} r dr d\phi $..is this the right way?

Comment: Take $y=0$ and $n=2$ to start. You can use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\omega_n$ denote the $n-1$ dimensional surface area of the $n-1$-sphere.

Your integrals, respectively, are
$$\int_{K_R(y)} |x-y|^\alpha \, dx= \int_0^R \int_{|x-y| = r} |x-y|^\alpha \, dx \, dr = n \omega_n \int_0^R |x-y|^{n+\alpha} \, dr$$
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus K_R(y)} |x-y|^\alpha  \, dx= \int_R^\infty \int_{|x-y| = r} |x-y|^\alpha \, dx \, dr = n \omega_n \int_R^\infty |x-y|^{n+\alpha} \, dr$$
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} |x-y|^\alpha  \, dx= \int_0^\infty \int_{|x-y| = r} |x-y|^\alpha \, dx \, dr = n \omega_n \int_0^\infty|x-y|^{n+\alpha} \, dr$$
where $dx$ is the usual $n$-dimensional volume element in the integrals on the left and the $n-1$ dimensional surface area element in the integrals in the middle.

The remaining improper integrals are straight forward to work out.